# TextInput in absolute positioned LinearGradient doesnot focus

Tags: react-native

I have a component with 2 LinearGradient views, both of them with absolute position and one with TextInput. For this setting, TextInput never gains focus in Android.

Code:

```
class SearchScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={['blue', 'red']}
          style={{
            height: 80,
            width: '100%',
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 10,
            elevation: 10,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
          }}
          start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
          end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
        >
          <TextInput
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              height: 50,
              paddingLeft: 15,
              marginTop: 10,
              marginBottom: 10,
              marginRight: 20,
              marginLeft: 20,
              borderWidth: 0,
            }}
            placeholder={'search placeholder'}
            onFocus={() => { console.log('onFocus: '); }}
            onChangeText={(text) => { console.log('enter text: ', text); }}
            onEndEditing={() => { console.log('endEditing: '); }}
          />
        </LinearGradient>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={['red', 'blue']}
          style={{
            height: 150,
            width: '100%',
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 5,
            elevation: 5,
          }}
        >
        </LinearGradient>
      </View >
    );
  }

}

export default SearchScreen;
```

React Native: 0.55.2
react-native-linear-gradient: 2.4.0

I found the problem is with the 2 absolute positioned LinearGradient View with Text Input. If I remove the one of the LinearGradient, the TextInput works fine as it should.

I've tried providing zIndex to the TextInput too, it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in the `zIndex` for android, as it works fine for IOS.

You can use it the following way as a workaround by **nesting of linear gradients** so that there is *no conflict for the overlay element that renders.*

```
 <LinearGradient
                    colors={['red', 'blue']}
                    style={{
                        height: 150,
                        width: '100%',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        zIndex: 5,
                        elevation: 5,
                    }}
                >
                    <LinearGradient
                        colors={['blue', 'red']}
                        style={{
                            height: 80,
                            width: '100%',
                            position: 'absolute',
                            zIndex: 10,
                            elevation: 10,
                            top: 0,
                            left: 0,
                        }}
                        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                        end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
                    >
                        <TextInput
                            style={{
                                backgroundColor: 'white',
                                height: 50,
                                paddingLeft: 15,
                                marginTop: 10,
                                marginBottom: 10,
                                marginRight: 20,
                                marginLeft: 20,
                                borderWidth: 0,
                            }}
                            placeholder={'search placeholder'}
                            onFocus={() => { console.log('onFocus: '); }}
                            onChangeText={(text) => { console.log('enter text: ', text); }}
                            onEndEditing={() => { console.log('endEditing: '); }}
                        />

                    </LinearGradient>

                </LinearGradient>
```